# bypass validation for form field django

Tags: python, django

```
            class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
                description = forms.CharField(widget=PagedownWidget(show_preview=False))
                class Meta:
                    model = Post
                    fields = [
                        'title',
                        'image',
                        'video',
                        'description',
                        'public',
                        'tags',
                        ]
```

I am trying to bypass the required field for 'video' but having difficulty doing so. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

this is my models.py, hopefully is should help with knowing how to go on this.

```
            from django.db import models

            from django.db.models import Count, QuerySet, F
            from django.utils import timezone
            from django.conf import settings
            from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
            from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
            from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
            from django.utils.text import slugify
            from markdown_deux import markdown
            from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
            from embed_video.fields import EmbedVideoField
            from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

            from comments.models import Comment

            def upload_location(instance, filename):
                return "%s/%s" %(instance.slug, filename)


            class Post(models.Model):
                user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1 )
                title = models.CharField(max_length=75)
                slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
                video = EmbedVideoField()
                image = models.ImageField(
                        upload_to=upload_location,
                        null=True,
                        blank=True,
                        width_field="width_field",
                        height_field="height_field")
                height_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
                width_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
                description = models.TextField()
                tags = TaggableManager()
                public = models.BooleanField(default=False)
                updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
                created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)


                def __str__(self):
                    return self.title

                def get_absolute_url(self):
                    return reverse("posts:detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

                class Meta:
                    ordering = ["-created", "-updated" ]

                def get_markdown(self):
                    description = self.description
                    markdown_text = markdown(description)
                    return mark_safe(markdown_text)

                @property
                def comments(self):
                    instance = self
                    qs = Comment.objects.filter_by_instance(instance)
                    return qs

                @property
                def get_content_type(self):
                    instance = self
                    content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(instance.__class__)
                    return content_type


            def create_slug(instance, new_slug=None):
                    slug = slugify(instance.title)
                    if new_slug is not None:
                        slug = new_slug
                    qs = Post.objects.filter(slug=slug).order_by("-id")
                    exists = qs.exists()
                    if exists:
                        new_slug = "%s-%s" %(slug, qs.first().id)
                        return create_slug(instance, new_slug=new_slug)
                    return slug



            def pre_save_post_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
                if not instance.slug:
                    instance.slug = create_slug(instance)


            pre_save.connect(pre_save_post_receiver, sender=Post)
```

Comment: I am currently using django-embed-video and it asks for the url of the video but makes it required to complete the form.

Comment: does your model field allow `blank` and/or `null` for the video field?  a model form will follow the restrictions set on the model itself

Comment: I went ahead and added my models.py. Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from [the docs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-embed-video) it looks like it should support empty now since version 0.3, i would suggest trying

```
video = EmbedVideoField(null=True,blank=True)
```

the docs say it should function like a URL field, so just the standard notation should be all you need.

good luck!

Comment: It worked, thanks! i was initially looking at required=False but no go. Thanks again.